# How to write this query about "order by `update time`" in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2.
How to write this query about "order by `update time`"?

There are 2 tables,`users` and `articles`,they have a "one-to-many" relationship,
I would want to query user's name and his/her article titles,and order by article's `update time`,
like this:

```
username    article titles                       update time
Lily        aaa-title-01;aaa-title-02;...        2016-04-20 12:00:00
Lucy        bbb-title-01;bbb-title-02;...        2016-04-19 12:00:00
Jim         ccc-title-01;ccc-title-02;...        2016-04-18 12:00:00
```

The `update time` is the user's latest article's update time, for example:

The first one, `username` is Lily, `update time` is `2016-04-20 12:00:00`,it represents that Lily's latest article was updated at `2016-04-20 12:00:00`.
The second one,it represents that Lucy's latest article was updated at `2016-04-19 12:00:00`.
Lily's latest article is later than Lucy's,so, Lily is the first,Lucy is the second,and..,Jim is the third.

**I writed the query like this:**

```
$articles =User::whereHas('articles', function($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1); //status is 1 or 0, 1 is published,0 is not published.
        })->get();
```

This query could get the user and his/her articles,but could not order by `update time` above,how to do it?

Comment: update time is field of articles, right?

Comment: @JoseRojas Yes,it is.

Comment: @MushangiDerrick 's anwer doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `orderBy` on the query and you should look good.

```
$articles =User::whereHas('articles', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1)->orderBy('update_time', 'desc');
})->get();
```